# Why using flexbox in container can prevent extra space of inline-block

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I use `inline-block`, I meet space problem. As many solutions propose [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) The solution that I liked best is using FlexBox. Just simple, we just add `display:flex` in container. As example below:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
   li {
  background: slategrey;
  display: inline-block;
  /* inline block hack for IE 6&7 */
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 4px;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<ul class="flexbox">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

My question is: Why FlexBox can prevent extra space of `inline-block`. (I know why extra space exist when using inline-block). I have read some documents about FlexBox but no document mentions clearly about relationship between flexbox and `inline-block`

Comment: because the flexmodel overrides child's display values ...

Comment: Can you explain me more detail, please ? Which values will flex model override ? If they override all attributes, so `inline-block` is useless ? thanks :)

Comment: @GCyrillus I have edited my question in code for clearer purpose. thanks

Comment: boltclock explains it all :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flex layout is [based on block layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-containers). Whitespace is ignored in both of these layout modes.

But in inline layout, whitespace between inline boxes is significant as [the whitespace is considered part of the inline content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop). As in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198315/to-which-element-does-inline-block-apply/30198391#30198391), this is akin to having a phrase consisting of two words separated by a space — whitespace between two inline blocks behaves exactly the same as such a space.<sup>1</sup>

Flex layout and inline-blocks have absolutely no relation whatsoever and are not compatible with one another. When you declare `display: flex` on a container, its children become flex items, which can never be displayed inline (they can contain their own inline contents, however).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This is also why I contend that [trying to remove whitespace between inline-blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) is really solving the wrong problem — you should never be using `inline-block` in the first place unless you well and truly understand inline layout and inline layout is actually what you need.</sub>

Comment: As I understand base on your explanation (and I have tested), if we removed line `display:inline-block` and `display:inline`, no thing changes in this case, right ? thanks :)

Comment: Moreover, I read many document they said prefer `inline-block` to `float`. As you take note (1), we should limit `inline-block` when we don't understand all and move to use `float` ?

Comment: @Trần Kim Dự: Yes, display: inline and inline-block have no effect as long as the parent element is display: flex. As for inline-block vs float, I'd rather not open that can of worms tonight :)

Comment: thanks :) So I think those tutorials I read, they put `display:inline-block` just for saving space for another examples. Just about experience, do you prefer using `display:flex` as a solution for above problem ? thanks :)