Stop flexbox from altering child dimensions in any way
I have the following markup on my page:
<h1 id="some-fragment">
    <a href="#some-fragment" class="fragment-link">
        <svg height="16" width="16" viewbox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2">
          <path d="M15 7h3a5 5 0 0 1 5 5 5 5 0 0 1-5 5h-3m-6 0H6a5 5 0 0 1-5-5 5 5 0 0 1 5-5h3"></path>
              <line x1="8" y1="12" x2="16" y2="12"></line>
        </svg>
    </a>
    Header text 
    <code>Ooh, a code block</code>
</h1>

with the following CSS:
/* irrelevant to this, but looks better */
a {
  text-decoration: none
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}

code {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

What I want to do is vertically align the icon next to the header text, but when I add display: flex, the code block looks super goofy. It gets crushed against the header text, losing the spacing following "text", and it seems to grow & get vertically off center, compared to the text. No combination of flex-grow: 0 has seemed to have an effect here.
I just want this to look identical to how it was w/out display: flex, but with the icon centered next to it.
Edit: I'm looking for CSS fixes, markup can't be adjusted really. The header text ("Header text " & ) are one item, can't be split up.

I think this will answer your query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198630/why-using-flexbox-in-container-can-prevent-extra-space-of-inline-block

It would not, no. That explains why the whitespace goes missing, but not why the code block grows in size, gets off-center, or how to fix this.

I have a solution for you but it does not make use of flexbox so I don't know if that is what you are looking for exactly.
CSS:
a {
    text-decoration: none
}

/*Removed Flexbox on h1*/

svg {
    display: inline-block;
    /*Converted the svg displpay type from block to inline-block*/
}

code {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    background: #888;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

The svg which you have made is aligned with the h1 heading and the padding given to the code block is preserved as well. It is only that flexbox is not being used.

I'm not sure you tried this, as the SVG is pretty far from vertically centered.

Oh my bad, I was checking the alignment of the anchor tag instead of the SVG.

Edited to handle additional criteria of not being able to edit the HTML on the page.
I've added a gap property to space the elements better.  Additonal horizontal spacing can be handled via margins & padding.
I've aligned the elements center, but then applied a "self" style to the code align-self: flex-end that overrides the center alignment of the parent.


a {
  text-decoration: none
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;

}

svg {
  display: block;
}

code {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 4px;
  align-self: flex-end;

}
<h1 id="some-fragment">
  <a href="#some-fragment" class="fragment-link">
    <svg height="16" width="16" viewbox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M15 7h3a5 5 0 0 1 5 5 5 5 0 0 1-5 5h-3m-6 0H6a5 5 0 0 1-5-5 5 5 0 0 1 5-5h3"></path>
      <line x1="8" y1="12" x2="16" y2="12"></line>
    </svg>
  </a>
  Header text
  <code>Ooh, a code block</code>
</h1>



Probably the best flexbox resource is here: Flexbox Tips and Tricks

Altering the markup is a no-go, sorry. I'm familiar with flexbox, but clearly not enough for whatever this situation is.

Oh, not being able to alter the markup is an important detail.

I've edited my response to handle your additional criteria
